# Whats Happening with the algorithm here, the code is related to a recursion problem in C?

Tags: c, recursion

The problem was to add the digits of a given number using recursion, for which I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int addition(signed int x);

int main() {
    signed int num;
    printf("enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d", addition(num));
    return 0;
}

int addition(signed int x) {
    signed int sum;
    sum = x % 10;
    x = x / 10;
    if (log10(x) + 1 == 1) {
        sum = sum + x;
    } else {
        sum = sum + addition(x);
    }
    return(sum);
}
```

This code works, but the weird problem with it is that, it is only adding digits of the number which starts with one. I can not understand whats going on and why is this happening. If any one can explain, that would be really helpful.

ps: I am a beginner with C so please tolerate and bear me.

thank you.

Comment: @sagi do you mean ` if(x == 1)`?

Comment: This is a good moment to learn to use a debugger. Sep through the program and see what it does or should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the `else` condition you will recurse infinitely because you're doing `addition(x)` with an `x` value of 0 which does *not* change the argument any further.

You don't really need `log10` [and the test is probably wrong].

Here's a cleaned up and working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int addition(int x);

int
main()
{
    int num;

    printf("enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("%d\n", addition(num));

    return 0;
}

int
addition(int x)
{
    int sum;

    sum = x % 10;
    x /= 10;

    if (x != 0)
        sum += addition(x);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @EOF Yes, I missed that. But, I pulled OP's code _unchanged_ and ran it with `23` as the input and I got a stack overflow/segfault. This happens when the `x` value reaches 0. So, it's probably the `log10` [which I eliminated] that was failing.